# LinkedIn V2 API error "Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER" when including timeRange params

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm replacing our LinkedIn V1 API integration with their V2 API, specifically the Company Pages endpoints described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/company-pages-migration

I've got an approved App, and a token with all of these scopes:
r_ads
r_ads_reporting
r_basicprofile
r_organization_social
rw_organization_admin
w_member_social
w_organization_social
w_share

All the first few v2 endpoints listed above work fine (getting company profile, updates) but as soon as I add their specific timeInterval parameters I get this 403 error:

```
Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/timeIntervals.timeGranularityType, /timeIntervals.timeRange.end, /timeIntervals.timeRange.start]
```

403 implies Access Denied but my token definitely includes the specific scopes they mention are needed for the Company Pages API. What am I missing here?

Specific example:
Headers:
Authorization: Bearer XXXXX
X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0

Endpoint:
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3AXXXXX&timeIntervals.timeGranularityType=DAY&timeIntervals.timeRange.start=1548892800000&timeIntervals.timeRange.end=1548892800000

If I remove all the timeInterval parameters it works fine, but I'm hoping to get historical data for our monthly social reporting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Submitted a ticket from LinkedIn support about this and got some clarification.

Under v2, the API doesn't use . notation for objects, but rather nested parenthesis. Much of their documentation still shows the . notation way (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/company-pages-migration)

But this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/protocol-version?context=linkedin/marketing/context has some more specifics on the correct notation for V2.

Specifically, my request above should look something like:

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3AXXXXX&timeIntervals=(timeRange:(start:1548892800000,end:1558892800000),timeGranularityType:MONTH)

Make sure the parenthesis don't get urlencoded by your platform too.

Comment: Thank you! This indirectly helped me fix a similar issue: looks like there are quite a few places in which V2 API docs use notation that is actually unsupported in practice.

Comment: Holy **** this took me all day to figure out...and I only figured it out because of your answer! Their docs suck!!

Comment: @Chris glad to hear it. Crazy it's been over 2 years and their docs are still not updated here.

Comment: @wakeman  - appreciate this detail , but I am still getting the same error as above wtih the url below :

url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&dateRange=(start:(day:1,month:1,year:2020))&timeGranularity=ALL&fields=impressions&account=urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredAccount%3A992225479'

Any idea why? Very Stuck

Comment: @0004 Can you share the specific error message? According to this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting) your parameters look correct as far as I can tell. If you're still stuck you might try reaching out to LinkedIn dev support. I'm not sure exactly where they have that set up at this point it's been a couple years since I tried to contact them, but they did provide clarity on the exact parameters I was missing.

Answer (score -1):

send in headers ..

```
data = {
    "Authorization":       "Bearer " + token['access_token'] ,
}
response   = requests.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me' , headers = data)
```

now works like a charm
contact me if you need help!.